# Why is the kinect presentation that slow on my computer?

Tags: c#, processing, kinect, openni

When using SimpleOpenNI and processing I had a smooth skeleton view, about 30fps. Using VC# and the skeletal tracking example it seems like about 10fps. As if something was blocking it.

Why is it that slow and how do I make it as fast as in processing?

pastebin.com/1La80sRU is the c# code basis - it is the original.

Comment: Did you try restarting? For some reason, that fixed it for me, although it was for Java

Comment: @Ramhound [This is Visual C#](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express)

Comment: First thing, make sure you are building for release.  I know C# emits IL but the JITer does take optimizations in to account.  Also check if C# example you're using sets up depth or rgb data.  I've had slow down on low end machines if I try to grab both depth and color at the same time as skeleton.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code, and to me it seems fine. I am using an Xbox-360 Kinect and the FPS is just fine. It seems to stumble a bit when you are first detected, but that is expected since it then requires more data. A video of me doing this can be found [here](http://youtu.be/fq1qgMfTrC0). It also seems that your Kinect needs to warm up (slower at beginning => gets faster later on). My video does not show that since I started recording after Kinect was warmed up.

Comment: This seems like a comment not an answer.